# What's the difference between "last working day" and "last employment day" in the UK?

Tags: new-job, resignation, united-kingdom, notice-period, employment

I have handed in my notice and will be leaving my current full time job in a month. However I have 1 week holiday which my current employer will pay me for. My employer tells me that my "last working day" will therefore be one week before my "last employment day". I want to start a new full time role directly after my "last working day" and therefore before my "last employment day". My current employer tells me that this is OK (and they're a large company so I believe them, to some degree).

I wanted to know whether this would be OK from an employment perspective? I assume this will mean that I am employed by both companies for a week?

And also, will this mean that I will end up getting emergency taxed for that month?

Comment: "My current employer tells me that this is OK (and they're a large company so I believe them, to some degree)." Why would you trust advice from amateurs on Stack Exchange over advice given by professional HR staff? They're *much* more likely to be correct than anything you get here.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I agree with you, but sometimes different perspectives are great

Comment: There is nothing in the UK stoping a person having two or more jobs.

Comment: to follow up James comment I certainly had no problem doing this when I left BT and started work with new employer before my last employed date

Answer (score 9):

**Last working day:**

The last day that you have to show up to the office to work, usually followed by a trip to the pub.

**Last employed day:**

The last day that you are contractually employed by the company. For example, if you have a 2 month notice period, but your boss sets the last working day as 1 month, with 1 month of gardening leave, the last day of gardening leave will be your last employed day.

You might want to check your contract to ensure you don't breach conflict of interest clauses if you start working earlier than this date.

**Taxes**

Emergency tax is not what you think it is. Emergency tax is a non-cumulative allocation of your personal allowance. You are probably confusing this with BR, which is where you have multiple jobs.

Fill in a P46 (new employee without P45) form when you start and you will get the apportionment of your allowance that month. If you get paid twice in the same period, you will get a double allowance, so might have to pay back some tax the next month (or at the end of the year if HMRC don't fix it straight away).

*Source: Former HMRC Revenue Officer and personal taxation specialist*

Comment: You can also factor in any unused holiday entitlement.  Normally, we use this up before the end of actual employment happens.  Usually, this reduces the notice period that you actually work.

Comment: +1 for the trip to the pub comment